Unable to delete Employee record using EmployeeId with common table expression (CTEs) in SQL?
I am trying to delete an employee record from Employee table which has 3 columns -EmpId(Primary Key),EmpName,DeptId(Foreign Key). There are 2 other tables as well Department having columns (DeptId-Primary Key,DeptName) and Salary having 3 columns as well-SalaryId(Primary Key), Amount (int type),EmpId-Foreign Key. I know we can do it without CTEs as well, but I want answer with CTEs as it is the only requirement). Can you please what's wrong in Query because I am getting an error

invalid Column "EmployeeCTE"

in the last line.
This was the SQL query that I wrote and I was expecting it to delete Employee record whose EmpId=2
WITH EmployeeCTE AS

(
SELECT EmpId
FROM Employee e
WHERE EmpId =2
)
\-- Delete related records from Salary table  
DELETE FROM Salary
WHERE EmpId IN (SELECT EmpId FROM EmployeeCTE)

\-- Delete the employee from Employee table

DELETE FROM Employee
WHERE EmpId IN (SELECT EmpId FROM EmployeeCTE);


EmployeeCTE belongs to the first DELETE, where it is declared. It only exists while that DELETE is executed, and can not be used from other statements.

There's no EmployeeCTE in the second query. A CTE is essentially a named subquery, not a view or script variable. It can't be shared among queries

as it is the only requirement is this homework or an interview test? Few things require a CTE, eg recursive queries. In most cases you can use a subquery

Also you don't need to rejoin, you can delete EmployeeCTE directly

The issue with your query lies in the fact that you are using WITH (the CTE declaration) and then attempting to run multiple DELETE statements without properly ending each statement. In SQL, the WITH clause is scoped to a single query or operation. If you want to perform multiple operations (like deleting from the Salary table and then the Employee table), you must either repeat the CTE or use separate WITH clauses for each operation.
Here's the corrected version of your query:
-- Declare the CTE
WITH EmployeeCTE AS (
    SELECT EmpId
    FROM Employee
    WHERE EmpId = 2
)
-- Delete related records from Salary table
DELETE FROM Salary
WHERE EmpId IN (SELECT EmpId FROM EmployeeCTE);

-- Declare the CTE again
WITH EmployeeCTE AS (
    SELECT EmpId
    FROM Employee
    WHERE EmpId = 2
)
-- Delete the employee from Employee table
DELETE FROM Employee
WHERE EmpId IN (SELECT EmpId FROM EmployeeCTE);

This should resolve the error you're encountering. Please try and let know.

The CTE table only exists for the first DELETE and is no longer available for the second. You should use a #TempTable or @VariableTable to collect deleted EmpIds. After that, you can use that table for joining and deleting rows that match with EmpIds.
